# Print Style Sheet doesn't seem to work

Tags: css

The print style sheet i had coded, doesn't seem to work. I tested it in all the browsers i have been using and it doesn't function as expected. The code is supposedly going to have a print view only of the tables that are displayed. The nav bar, header, footer, buttons, and all the rest should not be visible.

Here is the print style sheet i made:

```
 @media print{

   header nav, footer{
    display:none;
   }

   .clearfix, #sidebar, .columns btn-group{
    display:none;
   }

   @page{
    margin: 0.5cm;
   }

   body {
    font: 12pt Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    line-height: 1.3;
   }

 }
```

But when I print the page it still displays the unwanted elements as shown here in the pictures:
[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9unj.png)

While it is only suppose to print the tables in this part of the page:
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k31Vt.png)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that makes the problem reproducible.

Comment: Deleted my answer because it was wrong based on your comments

Comment: Is it also an issue that i am using a framework to develop my web app? I'm using Laravel 5. @nhouser9

Answer (score 0):

```
@media print{

   header nav, footer{
    display:none !important;
   }

   .clearfix, #sidebar, .columns btn-group{
    display:none !important;
   }

   @page{
    margin: 0.5cm !important;
   }

   body {
    font: 12pt Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
    line-height: 1.3 !important;
   }

 }
```

Then add **class='noprint'** (or add the no-print class to an existing class statement) in your HTML that you don't want to appear in the printed version, such as your button. I got this to work with 'noPrint' instead of 'noprint' (lowercase).

Comment: how do i add the no-print class?

Comment: i couldn't post the html code here, because it was too long. sorry. If you may, could you give me a sample on how i could put the no-print class?

Comment: i couldn't post the html code here, because it was too long. sorry. If you may, could you give me a sample on how i could put the no-print class?       @Vigneshwar

Comment: @media print  { .noprint  { display: none; } }

Comment: Is it also an issue that i am using a framework to develop my web app? I'm using Laravel 5. @Vigneshwar